# CompletableFuture with elapsed time information

Tags: java, asynchronous, lambda, java-8, completable-future

I need to have access to information about asynchronouos method execution time. So, I'm trying to extend [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) functionality. Here is my implementation with [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java) pattern usage:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import static lombok.AccessLevel.PRIVATE;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.Delegate;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
public class ContinuousCompletableFuture<T> extends CompletableFuture<T> {

    @Delegate
    private final CompletableFuture<T> baseFuture;

    private final long creationTime;

    public static <U> ContinuousCompletableFuture<U> supplyAsync(Supplier<U> supplier) {
        return new ContinuousCompletableFuture<>(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier));
    }

    private ContinuousCompletableFuture(CompletableFuture<T> baseFuture) {
        this.baseFuture = baseFuture;
        this.creationTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public Long getElapsedTime() {
        return (System.nanoTime() - creationTime) / 1000_000L;
    }

    public ContinuousCompletableFuture<Void> thenAcceptAsync(BiConsumer<? super T, Long> action) {
        CompletionStage<Long> elapsedTime = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getElapsedTime());
        return new ContinuousCompletableFuture<>(baseFuture.thenAcceptBothAsync(elapsedTime, action), creationTime);
    }
}
```

First test `shouldReturnElapsedTime` with extracted `ContinuousCompletableFuture` variable works fine, but other `shouldOperateWithOwnExecutionTime` fails. Meanwhile, I prefer to see it in my future code neither extracted `ContinuousCompletableFuture` variable.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@Slf4j
public class ContinuousCompletableFutureTest {

    private static final int DELAY = 1000;

    AtomicLong flag = new AtomicLong();

    ContinuousCompletableFuture<String> future;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        future = ContinuousCompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                log.error("Error during ContinuousCompletableFuture execution", ex);
            }
            return "successfully completed";
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnElapsedTime() {
        future.thenAcceptAsync(s -> {
            long t = future.getElapsedTime();
            log.info("Elapsed {} ms to receive message \"{}\"", t, s);
            flag.set(t);
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.error("Error awaiting Test completion", ex);
        }

        assertTrue("Future completion should be delayed", flag.get() >= 0.75 * DELAY);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldOperateWithOwnExecutionTime() {
        future.thenAcceptAsync((s, t) -> {
            log.info("Elapsed {} ms to receive message \"{}\"", t, s);
            flag.set(t);
        });

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            log.error("Error awaiting Test completion", ex);
        }

        assertTrue("Future completion should be delayed", flag.get() >= 0.75 * DELAY);
    }
}
```

I assume that my issue lies in wrong `thenAcceptBothAsync` method usage.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I ran both your tests and there were no errors.

Comment: @Tunaki that's strange for me - here is my output  from both tests: `Elapsed 1 ms to receive message "successfully completed"` and `Elapsed 993 ms to receive message "successfully completed"`. In `shouldOperateWithOwnExecutionTime` elapsed time was calculated as it was executed without any delay.

Comment: Do note that I had to fix the code you posted to make it compile: I added a constructor taking 2 parameters to `ContinuousCompletableFuture`.

Comment: You are invoking `getElapsedTime()` right in your `thenAcceptAsync` method. Of course, at that point almost to time has elapsed. And that long value doesn’t change afterward…

Comment: @Holger Should I chanage return type of `getElapsedTime()` from `Long` type to `Supplier<Long>` type or there are better solutions?

Comment: I’m not sure about your goal but to me it looks like you don’t need it at all. What you actually want, seems to be `return new ContinuousCompletableFuture<>(baseFuture.thenAcceptAsync(t -> action.accept(t, getElapsedTime())), creationTime);`

Comment: @Holger Your solution is great, all now works as intended. Thank you. I will accept your answer if you post it. I thought a lot about how to translate `BiConsumer` -> `Consumer`, but didn't find nice `t -> action.accept(t, getElapsedTime())` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method

```
public ContinuousCompletableFuture<Void> thenAcceptAsync(
                                         BiConsumer<? super T, Long> action) {
    CompletionStage<Long> elapsedTime=CompletableFuture.completedFuture(getElapsedTime());
    return new ContinuousCompletableFuture<>(
        baseFuture.thenAcceptBothAsync(elapsedTime, action), creationTime);
}
```

you are evaluating `getElapsedTime()` immediately and pass the result to the `BiConsumer` unchanged, regardless of the actual completion time.

You can fix it by querying the elapsed time right in the consumer:

```
public ContinuousCompletableFuture<Void> thenAcceptAsync(
                                         BiConsumer<? super T, Long> action) {
    return new ContinuousCompletableFuture<>(
        baseFuture.thenAcceptAsync(t -> action.accept(t, getElapsedTime())), creationTime);
}
```